# How to construct a Z3 solver from a Query in txt

Tags: z3, smt

I am in a situation where I have a bunch of Z3(bitvector) queries already in txt format. Is there a way to create a solver and a context through some API by reading in those queries? I am more of a java programmer, so I'd be in favor of some Java API, but c and python should be fine as well.

Much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming those queries are in SMTLib format, you're looking for:

- C: [Z3_solver_from_string](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga99cf23fd04f40e63e8ea8b94030d0ac2)
- Python: [parse_smt2_string](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a09fe122cbfbc6d3fa30a79850b2a2414)
- Java: [fromString](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/java/Solver.java#L186)

In the reverse direction:

- C: [Z3_solver_to_string](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#gae8610a38a4a6d7389c57995517011035)
- Python: [sexpr](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3py_1_1_solver.html#ab41c56f8b1c61ace1b28a163103d86b4)
- Java: [toString](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/java/Solver.java#L342)

Comment: A continuation perhaps to that, is there a way to obtain the reverse, that is given a solver say in Java is there a way to print the SMTLib format for it. From what I see the toString() is missing "assert" keyword as well as missing some setup for the query. It is also missing definitions of various functions. Thanks!

Comment: Sure; see my updated answer. Note that you have to `add` all those constraints to the solver instance and then call `toString`.

Comment: Well, actually the toString in java, is not doing this job. In fact, the toString of a solver gives you part of the query but not all of it. That is, it is missing headers, and assert keyword plus declarations of vars. That is whatever is generated from the toString() can't be thrown to z3 binary right away , I had to do some text manipulation to make it a valid z3 query. I was hoping there would be another function that would do this job. I ended up implementing that.

Comment: If `toString` isn't working correctly, it could very well be a bug. I'd recommend filing a ticket at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues so it can be addressed properly. This ticket also has a  use case: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1283

Comment: Actually it turned out that you are correct, I installed the latest z3 and toString is doing the intended purpose. I guess I have an old version that is being used in a project that I am working on. Thank you!